# Resource ID hashmap creation and passing around

Tags: java, android

Okay, I've searched all over and done a bunch of reading and I see now what I'm doing wrong with the below code, especially the concern of a memory leak in doing what I'm attempting to do. But, I'm not quite sure how to do this in a different way. Here's the code:

```
public class SoundPlayer extends Activity {

private String sound;
private SoundPool soundPool;
private float fSpeed = 1;
private int resID;

public SoundPlayer(String s) {
    sound = s;
}

public SoundPlayer(String s, float f) {
    sound = s;
    fSpeed = f;
}

public void playSound() {
    resID = WorkoutStopwatch.getResources().getIdentifier(sound, "raw", "com.blueflamesys.workoutstopwatch");
    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float streamVolumeCurrent = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float streamVolumeMax = mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float volume = streamVolumeCurrent / streamVolumeMax;

    soundPool.play(resID, volume, volume, 1, 0, fSpeed);
}
}
```

I'm trying to create an activity (although, after some of the reading I've seen, I think I just need a class and not an activity) to play a sound. This sound will be one of a number of raw files, hence the resID variable setting, and the error I get trying to call getResources() from a non-static method. The refactored class looks like this:

```
public class SoundPlayer extends {

private SoundPool soundPool;
private float fSpeed = 1;
private int resID;

public SoundPlayer(int r) {
    resID = r;
}

public SoundPlayer(int r, float f) {
    resID = r;
    fSpeed = f;
}

public void playSound() {       
    soundPool.play(resID, 1, 1, 1, 0, fSpeed);
    }
}
```

Since there's multiple sounds that I'd prefer to address by a String I guess the best thing to do would be to create a hashmap with the key as a string representing the sound and the value as the int resID? Although doing this makes a mess out of the main application code. I guess it doesn't really matter, but I was wondering if this is the right approach, or if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: You're right, it should not extend Activity, only classes which are, er, an activity should do that and only for starting with Intent.  You should also do some basic Java (actually, any programming) reading and understand exactly what static means before moving on.  You sometimes need to step back in order to make progress and you've skipped over some of the basic stuff.

Comment: I thought I had the static stuff understood pretty well. Static variables are common to all of the objects that are instantiated. In this particular case, none will be static as any of the enclosed variables would be different from object to object. Is this incorrect thinking?

Comment: Ah, OK, got it.  You're right about your understanding.  However, getResources() is not static (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) but you are trying to call it in a static way (or at least, I'm assuming that `WorkoutStopWatch` is a class.

Comment: Sorry, after banging my head against this for a few hours I guess my post wasn't really that clear about what I was really asking. I edited my post with the real question.